Problema de serial entre Arduino y Python
Estoy intentando enviar bytes desde el serial Arduino para un dispositivo serial de RS232 de StarTech en el que recibe la información serial desde un puerto RS232 que está conectado con el RX/TX del Arduino. Aquí hay el pequeño código del Arduino para lograr comunicarse:
const byte age = 24;

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() 
{
  Serial.write(age);  // Envía el byte
  delay(1000);
}

En este caso, de la otra parte estoy utilizando un pequeñp codigo python que lee los datos que vienen del puerto seleccionado y lo muestra, pero no recibo los datos como se debe y nose si tengo problema en la conversión o la forma de enviarlos. Aqui es le código Python:
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM37', 9600)

while True:
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:  
        data = ser.read(1)  
        age = int.from_bytes(data, byteorder='big') 
        
        print(f"Edad recibida: {age}")
´´´´




Y esto es lo que recibo en la salida :
Edad recibida: 127
Edad recibida: 0








¿Por qué no estás usando el default SERIAL_8N1 https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/begin/ ?

Lo he intentando antes pero me da lo mismo y me da caracteres más raros además y pasé al .write pero el problema sigue allí
